# Angular web component directive its not working

Tags: angular13, angular-elements

I am trying to convert angular components to angular web component, I followed few articles to do it which is good, but when I tried to convert angular directive as web component it throws some error which I am not able to figure out what is wrong I am doing, also I don't have any idea on can we convert an angular directive to angular web component. Below is code which I tried to convert directive as web component.

**Tooltip Directive:**

```
<pre>@directive({
    selector: '[tooltip]'
})
export class TooltipDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
      this.el.nativeElement.classList.add('my-tooltip');
      }
    }</pre>
```

**Creation of tooltip web components snippet:**

```
<pre>export class AppModule implements DoBootstrap {
     constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

     ngDoBootstrap() {
       const webTooltip = createCustomElement(TooltipDirective, {
          injector: this.injector,
      });
      customElements.define("web-tooltip", webTooltip);
      }
    }
</pre>
```

**How I am trying to use in app HTML file is below code**

Web tooltip selector:

```
<span web-tooltip id="tooltip" content="This is a tooltip.">
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ossB0.png)

If I try to write same code for any component its working fine but for directive as I shown code above its not working.

Comment: did you find any answer for this requirement?
if yes, please share the details

Comment: Hi @RealSteel did you find a solution? If yes, kindly share the details